# how to compare value of new calculated column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am runnning this query

```
  select 
    case when "Payment Collection Fee" = 0  then
    round(("Comm (Incl. S.Tax)" - ((("Marketing Fee" *16)/100)+"Marketing Fee"+0+"Courier Fee")),2) 
    when "Web Sale Price" < 0 then round(("Comm (Incl. S.Tax)" - ((("Marketing Fee" *16)/100)+"Marketing Fee"-20+"Courier Fee")),2) 
    else
       round(("Comm (Incl. S.Tax)" - ((("Marketing Fee" *16)/100)+"Marketing Fee"+20+"Courier Fee")),2) 
    end as diff

  from 
    meta.sd_payment_error
```

now i want to add condition

```
  where diff > 10
```

but it giving error diff column does not exist

how i can add condition to above query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Common Table Expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html) :

```
WITH diffs AS (
  select 
    case 
    when "Payment Collection Fee" = 0
       then round(("Comm (Incl. S.Tax)" - ((("Marketing Fee" *16)/100)+"Marketing Fee"+0+"Courier Fee")),2) 
    when "Web Sale Price" < 0 
       then round(("Comm (Incl. S.Tax)" - ((("Marketing Fee" *16)/100)+"Marketing Fee"-20+"Courier Fee")),2) 
    else
       round(("Comm (Incl. S.Tax)" - ((("Marketing Fee" *16)/100)+"Marketing Fee"+20+"Courier Fee")),2) 
    end as diff
  from 
    meta.sd_payment_error
)
SELECT diff
FROM diffs
WHERE diff > 10
```

Comment: your query is working correctly . i have a question .  Is  your query is count as in single query or multiple ?

Comment: @Shubhambatra:  It's a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table:

```
select *
from
(
select 
    case when "Payment Collection Fee" = 0  then
    round(("Comm (Incl. S.Tax)" - ((("Marketing Fee" *16)/100)+"Marketing Fee"+0+"Courier Fee")),2) 
    when "Web Sale Price" < 0 then round(("Comm (Incl. S.Tax)" - ((("Marketing Fee" *16)/100)+"Marketing Fee"-20+"Courier Fee")),2) 
    else
       round(("Comm (Incl. S.Tax)" - ((("Marketing Fee" *16)/100)+"Marketing Fee"+20+"Courier Fee")),2) 
    end as diff

  from 
    meta.sd_payment_error
) as dt
where dt.diff > 10
```